# JavaScript button value limited to first button only. How to overcome?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to get my JS to display the relevant output based on button selection.

I only get the first value returned, so selecting button A returns "You selected: A" as expected, but selecting button B or C does nothing.

Here's an example of my html:

```js
let userSelection = document.querySelector('.userOutput');
let selected = document.querySelector('button');

selected.addEventListener('click', userPicked);

function userPicked() {

  let choice = selected.value;

  if (choice === 'a') {
    userSelection.textContent = 'You selected: A';
  } else if (choice === 'b') {
    userSelection.textContent = 'You selected: B';
  } else if (choice === 'c') {
    userSelection.textContent = 'You selected: C';
  } else {
    userSelection.textContent = "Error"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="allbuttons">
  <button class="btn" value="a">A</button>
  <button class="btn" value="b">B</button>
  <button class="btn" value="c">C</button>
</div>
<p class="userOutput"></p>
```

I've seen that this could be affected by 'closure', but can't see how to overcome that specifically (if it is that).

Comment: Your code only attaches a click handler to the first `button` element. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `.querySelector()` which finds the **first element** that matches your selector, in your case, the "A" button and that's the button that you've set up your `click` event handler on, so that's the only button that works. Instead, use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and just return the value of the clicked event target.

```js
let userSelection = document.querySelector('.userOutput');

// Set up a click event on the document, so any click will trigger the callback
document.addEventListener('click', userPicked);

function userPicked(evt) {
    // Check to see if the actual object clicked is one of the buttons
    if(evt.target.classList.contains("btn")){
      // Return the value of the clicked button
      userSelection.textContent = evt.target.value;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="allbuttons">
   <button class="btn" value="a">A</button>
   <button class="btn" value="b">B</button>
   <button class="btn" value="c">C</button>
</div>
<p class="userOutput"></p>
```

Comment: This would be better written by having the delegate filter the event and then exercise the callback specific to the filtered element

Comment: @Tibrogargan Why? Explain why that would be better than simply filtering on the element in the first place since that's what the callback actually cares about. Filtering on an event? The event will always be `click`. How are you supposed to filter on that? Delegation is about filtering on the event target - - the thing that caused the event.

Comment: This answer suggests that for every instance where you want behavior attached to an event you need to add an event listener that filters to the correct set of elements and then implements the desired function within the handler.  This leads to exactly the same type of inefficiency you attribute to my answer.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Uh, no it doesn't. I don't think you understand event delegation and how memory is affected by setting up event handlers. My answer sets up **one** event callback no matter how many buttons you have. **It does this without a DOM scan or any loops**. Your's requires a scan of the DOM and a loop over all the found elements, just to get to the point of then creating a callback for each found element. There is no equivalency in your approach vs. mine as far as efficiency goes.

Answer (score 1):

this a classic event delegation system:

```js
const All_Buttons = document.querySelector('.allbuttons')
  ,   user_Output = document.querySelector('.userOutput')


All_Buttons.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (e.target.className!='btn') return // ignore other clicks on area
  user_Output.textContent = `You selected: ${e.target.value.toUpperCase()}`
  }
```

```html
<div class="allbuttons">
  <button class="btn" value="a">A</button>
  <button class="btn" value="b">B</button>
  <button class="btn" value="c">C</button>
</div>
<p class="userOutput"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method querySelector() returns the **first** Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

While you should really implement event delegation (as demonstrated in a number of places), to get a collection of elements what you probably want is [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which you could use to modify your selection to get all your buttons and add the event handler to all of them:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.btn'))
     .forEach((selected) => selected.addEventListener('click', userPicked) )
```

You should also use `this` in the event handler instead of attempting to use the global `selected` since the value is not being updated during the click event.

Be careful here though, there is a trade-off between adding an event handler to every single object and adding an event handler to the entire page.  Adding handlers to all objects does not scale well.  Adding a global handler means you may need to be aware of anything else that might need to interact with the same event.  @MisterJojo's answer is a good example of event delegation that restricts the handler to just the containing element.

Demo:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')]
  .forEach((selected) => selected.addEventListener('click', userPicked));
     
let outputForButton = (value) => {
  switch(value) {
    case 'a': return 'You selected: A';
    case 'b': return 'You selected: B';
    case 'c': return 'You selected: C';
    default: return 'Error';
  }
}

function userPicked() {
  document.querySelector('.userOutput').textContent =
    outputForButton(this.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="allbuttons">
   <button class="btn" value="a">A</button>
   <button class="btn" value="b">B</button>
   <button class="btn" value="c">C</button>
</div>
<p class="userOutput"></p>
```

Comment: Two things here... 1) This will not work in any version of IE  2) Attaching handlers to each button can be wasteful when you can just use event delegation.

Comment: And what trade off it that? Executing a function that first checks to see if it should proceed, so that it doesn't perform tasks unnecessarily, is preferable than taking up memory on multiple DOM objects.

Comment: So if you’re worried about performance, this answer shows what not to do. Now, you’ve got a loop, with a callback containing a condition. This is a perfect use case for why event delegation exists.

Comment: My answer does show the right output - the value of the clicked button. And, the only time a delegate will interfere is when the pattern isn't implemented properly. The fact is, this answer scans the DOM to gather up all the matching elements, then loops over each of them, then adds an event binding to each and within that event binding implements condition testing. Will this work and is it acceptable? Sure, I'm simply saying that setting up a single event binding and eliminating the constant testing to determine which button got clicked, is not only more simple, but also more efficient.

Comment: You're splitting hairs. Obtaining the value of the clicked element is the primary goal of the question. Placing static text next to it is trivial and not what the question was asking. I think the OP marking my answer as "the" answer shows this.

Comment: Again, I say that I don't think you understand delegation or memory. There is nothing more efficient about the other answer, it simply intercepts the event sooner, but shows the exact same principle. The event will still bubble to the `document`. Instead of arguing my perfectly valid comments (and that's all they were by the way - I didn't down vote you), you might just try to learn something.

Comment: And I think you need to learn that efficiency != complexity. Would it be better to handler the event closer to the originator, sure. Did I say otherwise? But (again), that doesn't make that solution more efficient, it makes it less complex. But, this is besides the point. I've been talking about your solution and when I clearly point out the problems with it, you switch and start comparing my solution against others. Again, try to learn something here.

Comment: Yo do understand that the event is going to bubble up to the `document` whether there are handlers there or not, right? It's no less efficient handling it there than anywhere else. We're talking about code efficiency here. Stop changing the subject. And, if you took the time to read and understand my comments, you'd see that I did freely acknowledge that my code could be improved, but you have shifted from comparing your code and mine to mine and other people's. I was commenting on YOUR code, not other people's.

Comment: Oh, and by the way using `Array.prototype.slice.call()` to convert the collection returned from `.querySelectorAll()` into an actual array so that you can safely call `.forEach()` in browsers that don't support `.forEach()` on node lists is a good idea, but those same browsers don't support arrow functions, so the second part of the code would still cause the code to error out. If you are going to use arrow functions, then just call `.forEach()` on the node list because any browser that does arrows will do `forEach` on a node list.

Comment: I was trying to get that poster to realize the very same point I just made to you... If you are going to use Arrow Functions, then protecting `.forEach()` usage makes no sense. But, it is still lost on you. If that wasn't new to you as you say, then you purposefully wrote bad code. Is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the `click` event to **only** the first `button`, Why ? As of the `querySelector` method returns the **first** occurrence of the `selector` parameter you pass to it (in your case the `selector` is `button`).

So instead, you could use the `querySelectorAll` method to get all the `button`s (based on the `selector`) and then you **HAVE** to **cycle through** the returned array like object (`NodeList` containing an `Element` object for each element matching the `selector`).

So, here's the updated code :

```js
let userSelection = document.querySelector('.userOutput'),
  selected = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn'); // just to be more specific.

// loop through the buttons.
[].forEach.call(selected, (el) => {
  // add the listener
  el.addEventListener('click', () => userSelection.textContent = el.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="allbuttons">
  <button class="btn" value="a">A</button>
  <button class="btn" value="b">B</button>
  <button class="btn" value="c">C</button>
</div>
<p class="userOutput"></p>
```

Am here for any further clarifications.

Comment: Why `[].forEach.call(selected, (el)` and not just `selected.forEach(....)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let userSelection = document.querySelector('.userOutput');
let selected = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

selected.forEach((x,i) => {
  x.addEventListener('click', function() {
    userSelection.innerHTML = 'You have selected: ' + this.textContent
  })
})
```

Scotts answer works as well, this is another way to handle it.

`querySelector()` only targets the first element of its kind.  If you use `querySelectorAll()` you get a variable that holds an object of all instances of the element.  That allows you to iterate over it.  I also recommend using `id="someId"` for your output element, for more precision.

jQuery Solution

```
let userSelection = $('.userOutput')
let selected = $('.btn')

selected.click(function() {
  userSelection.html('You have selected: ' + $(this).text())
})
```

https://codepen.io/mujakovic/pen/zVJRKG